# sharing cookie and session between subdomain

Tags: php, jquery, .htaccess, session

I have m.xxxx.com and www.xxxx.com subdomains
all my project in the www.xxx.com and when I need to send ajax request like login and so on
it return value but when I call it again the session and cookie removed

I was testing the application www.xxxx.com/mobile

and all the request where worked probebly what should I do

and also sitting `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*;`

for the cross origin problem but the session not sharing between those two subdomains

Comment: please explain more. are you saying that cookies not working for your site?

Comment: Set cookie for `.xxx.com`, also session should be set to the needed domain (e.g. `.xxx.com`).

Comment: DUPLICATE:there are so many threads on this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9814400/sharing-session-variables-in-php-between-subdomains
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064243/php-sessions-across-sub-domains

Comment: I tried all solution exists and nothing working

Comment: my problem is when I logined in www.xxx.com to be logined in m.xxx.com but it not working

Comment: I don't want to add php files into the m.xxxx.com to apply it later on PhoneGap application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

> The only way I can think of to do this would be to save the session data to a cookie, then open the cookie when the other domain is accessed. You can read how to do this here:

http://www.depiction.net/tutorials/php/cookies-session-variables.php

why do you want to do this?

or

Also you can try

You are looking for this function: `session_set_cookie_params()`. Say you have two domains:

```
site1.example.com
site2.example.com
```

In order to share your session data across both domains, call the following function before `session_start()`:

```
session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '.example.com');
```

Comment: for the mobile version so I don't want to change all over the code and make the same existing functionality